# Unable to Find PostgreSQL Logs, Configuration Files, or Create Users/Databases (Version 15.5, macOS Sonoma 14.0, Homebrew, Mac M2)

Tags: database, postgresql, logging, homebrew

I'm encountering multiple issues with my PostgreSQL setup on an Apple Mac M2 running macOS Sonoma 14.0 using version 15.5, installed via Homebrew.

Key Details:

Operating system: macOS Sonoma 14.0
Hardware: Apple Mac M2
PostgreSQL version: 15.5
Installation method: Homebrew
Installation path: /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15

Observations:

Missing logs: Unable to locate PostgreSQL logs in standard or Homebrew-specific directories.
Missing configuration files: Neither postgresql.conf nor pg_hba.conf could be found in expected locations (/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/data and /usr/local/var/postgresql@15).
Failed user/database creation: Running CREATE USER [username] and CREATE DATABASE [dbname] within the psql shell does not create the user or database, despite no explicit error messages.

Request for Assistance:

Where might the logs reside in this non-standard setup, potentially considering any Mac M2-specific behaviors?
Are there any overlooked configuration settings or Homebrew-specific behaviors affecting logging and file locations?
How can I successfully create users and databases, given the absence of error messages but lack of actual creation?
Are alternative methods available to enable or access logs?
Any guidance on resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) Did you add the `;` at the end of command e.g. `CREATE DATABASE some_db;`? 2) Have you searched for `pg_hba.conf` across the disk?

Comment: Thanks for the quick assist! The missing semicolon was definitely my bad. I could also find the pg_hba.conf using `sudo find pg_hba.conf` Thank you very much.